# Without iPhone, how to take screenshot with XCode?

Tags: xcode, screenshot

I'm building iPhone / iPad app with Xcode.
now i want to take screenshot of this application.

with 960x640 size.

so how to?
the screen on simulator is too small

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `cmd+S` into the simulator, it will capture the screen.

Image will be saved to the Desktop.

Comment: but the size is not fit with apple requirement (only 640 x 480)

Comment: Change the device to iPhone (Retina), it'll be the right size.

Comment: where i can change iPhone simulator to retina display?

Comment: In the menu bar, you might have device (mine is in french, not sure of the translation). Anyway it's after Edit and before Debug. Then it's the first item in the menu (device ?).

Comment: Note: the screenshot is saved to the desktop with the prefix `iOS Simulator Screen shot`. E.g. `iOS Simulator Screen shot May 22, 2014, 11.42.51 AM`

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator navigate to

> Hardware>>Device>>iPhone (Retina)

Then you can use command-s to capture the simulators screen in retina, and the screenshot requirement is 640x960.

Keep in mind, the retina simulator screen may not fit vertically on your screen depending on its resolution.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use cmd+shift+4 to take screenshot with the iphone frame in it.